# Take control of the screen

Tags: command-line, gnome, ssh, 16.10

I'm currently using Ubuntu Gnome 16.10. I know it is possible to take control of the terminal of a remote machine with `ssh` command. Is it possible to take control of the whole screen of a remote machine (with or without the consent of the person)? If so, how could we do that?

Comment: If you have root access on remote system, sure. Lookup VNC. I run x11vnc via SSH and then connect to it with Remmina on the local system (very useful for logging in to the GUI remotely).

Comment: @muru This seems very INTERESTING. Could you display a full answer (with examples if possible)?

Comment: Vim. Only Emacs command I know is C-x C-c.  I'll try to add an answer, but it will take time.

Comment: @muru Take your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have their consent, I can't see why you don't just use TeamViewer.

Comment: Ok, but if you don't?

Comment: @SpinningAtInfinity FYI Teamviewer can be set up to allow remote logins without the user's permission, but it does need to be installed and configured on the target computer first.

Comment: Yes, I know well this software, but I'd like something clever